# How can I say something is "grippable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe something as "possible to be held".

Neither *"holdable"* or *"grippable"* are words, and I really need it to be one word, for simplicity.

Example:

> The product is the perfect X size.

Comment: Most people wouldn't think twice if you used "grippable".

Comment: Please (as per guidelines re. single word requests) give us an example of its use. That will help towards better answers.

Comment: Holdable, btw, is a word:   capable of being held ,  of a size or character that makes holding convenient or desirable.http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holdable

Comment: @medica done it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As related in comment, both "*holdable*" and "*grippable*" are usable and easily understood, but for good measure here's another option:

> **graspable**, *adjectival form of*
>
> **grasp** *verb* (*used with object*)
>
> **1**. to seize and hold by or as if by clasping with the fingers or arms.
>
> **2**. to seize upon; hold firmly. See, Dictionary.com [**grasp**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/graspable)